# Reduce helper window size

Tags: rstudio

I know this is a really trivial question but I'm struggling. Whenever I type something like

```
?(some_function)
```

my screen looks like this. I want to be able to see my code still but I don't know how to move it back.

[image]

So I can't see my code and I don't know how to move the window to be smaller again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the windows size with `ctrl+shift+number` with various result based on the number you use. ([see shortcuts](https://appsilon.com/r-studio-shortcuts-and-tips/))

Otherwise, under the Project none on the top right corner of the picture you provide, there is 2 rectangles which allow to reduce partly the current windows inside Rstudio.

Lastly, there are many options in the `view` panel or in `Tools > Global options > Pane layout`

Comment: ctr + shft+ 3 it what I had toggled. Thank you!